# How do I convert timestamp to unix format with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with timestamp values, like this one: 2018-02-15T11:39:13.000Z
I want to have it in UNIX format, using Pyspark.

I tried something like `data = datasample.withColumn('timestamp_cast', datasample['timestamp'].cast('date'))` but I lose a lot of information, since I only get day/month/year when I have milliseconds information in my source.

Result: `2018-02-15`

Any idea to get unix format and keep precision? Thank you!

Comment: You need to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.unixtimestamp`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the built in `unix_timestamp` the following ways:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
df = df.withColumn('unix', unix_timestamp('timestamp'))
```

Or

```
df = df.selectExpr('unix_timestamp(timestamp)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible method is to directly `cast` the column to integer

```
df.withColumn('timestamp_unix', F.col('timestamp').cast('int'))
```